# Getting 503 error with HttpUrlConnection but site loading on browser

Tags: java, httpresponse, httpurlconnection

```java
     url = "https://www.lmcu.org/?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=9c114404052361017d9cfe1247981e24813649c7-1592389426-0-AfP07ha5TxZHf64q5tb5nJf9BJguC4U553-OJzJWivTqfgwYLqUODkXj-XsOjZTwpC71ROxHWx4Xhdp2S0LgAVlKgXpy7KWOex7lkoGBm8mNpBsCeJapdYNWty-X2oHE6gp_TtMfH0dcBabvWr_mXV1djsVR_IGlYJA-wCuZpPTGOozyzN9TFwjMPxU-3o6BIUxTh6DDcHmJ_Bw48EYKGpq6n57bVdeLezEs9PduataW1JUcF4GqLE2EHiUxWGubtS8YgcxkkGin4zitHXENMbFi1kMhxI77LsORzKyhkAD1OkG8fGmV--Cgd3EpxWHtHD5vpoIFFIwX0uGQywPnegs";

     HttpURLConnection connection = pingHttpUrl(url);
     responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

     public HttpURLConnection pingHttpUrl(String url) throws IOException {

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

            conn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76 Safari/537.36");
            conn.setConnectTimeout(2000);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
            conn.connect();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Caught exception : {}", e.getMessage());
            throw new IOException();
        }

        return conn;
     }
```

This gives response code as 503. But the site is properly loading on browser. What can be the issue with this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the headers of the request. I found that this solution hosted on cloudflare requires two headers to be just so, otherwise you will receive the `503` response:

- **User-Agent** - Your header specified chrome version **76**, apparently the server has a problem with this. I had success with this `User-Agent` value: `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36`
- **cookie** - I found that the cookie value `cf_clearance` needs to be set, and possibly the other `set-cookie` values that are returned on the first request. This value has to do with the cloudflare support for privacy pass (https://blog.cloudflare.com/cloudflare-supports-privacy-pass/). It appears to be a means of verifying that a user is human, and not a machine. Which in turn is bad news for your efforts here.

I have a working solution below, but it will be hard to automate - since it will require you to establish a browser session, and use the cookie set there in the code. Upon expiration of the cf_clearance cookie, you will have visit the site again and reset the cookie value in the code.

I would also speculate that the User-Agent header of the request, is used in generating the cf_clearance cookie that is required. Making it more difficult to hijack the cookie, as you would have to use a matching User-Agent of the browser used for the request when the cf_clearance cookie was generated by cloudflare.

I have journaled my investigation here:

When visiting the URL in my browser:

[https://www.lmcu.org/?**cf_chl_jschl_tk**=9c114404052361017d9cfe1247981e24813649c7-1592389426-0-AfP07ha5TxZHf64q5tb5nJf9BJguC4U553-OJzJWivTqfgwYLqUODkXj-XsOjZTwpC71ROxHWx4Xhdp2S0LgAVlKgXpy7KWOex7lkoGBm8mNpBsCeJapdYNWty-X2oHE6gp_TtMfH0dcBabvWr_mXV1djsVR_IGlYJA-wCuZpPTGOozyzN9TFwjMPxU-3o6BIUxTh6DDcHmJ_Bw48EYKGpq6n57bVdeLezEs9PduataW1JUcF4GqLE2EHiUxWGubtS8YgcxkkGin4zitHXENMbFi1kMhxI77LsORzKyhkAD1OkG8fGmV--Cgd3EpxWHtHD5vpoIFFIwX0uGQywPnegs](https://www.lmcu.org/?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=9c114404052361017d9cfe1247981e24813649c7-1592389426-0-AfP07ha5TxZHf64q5tb5nJf9BJguC4U553-OJzJWivTqfgwYLqUODkXj-XsOjZTwpC71ROxHWx4Xhdp2S0LgAVlKgXpy7KWOex7lkoGBm8mNpBsCeJapdYNWty-X2oHE6gp_TtMfH0dcBabvWr_mXV1djsVR_IGlYJA-wCuZpPTGOozyzN9TFwjMPxU-3o6BIUxTh6DDcHmJ_Bw48EYKGpq6n57bVdeLezEs9PduataW1JUcF4GqLE2EHiUxWGubtS8YgcxkkGin4zitHXENMbFi1kMhxI77LsORzKyhkAD1OkG8fGmV--Cgd3EpxWHtHD5vpoIFFIwX0uGQywPnegs)

And inspecting the response that the server is giving, it turns out that it is infact giving back a `503` as well:

[image: Image of browser developer console, with network output]

For some reson that I can't make out, the browser is redirected to the below URL instead. I cannot see that the location header is passed back in the response, or find this URL anywhere in the response.

[https://www.lmcu.org/?**cf_chl_jschl_tk**=fe835fdc1e7e2f5b2857ab5eb4be84e67d0e8c42-1592506549-0-AQ3E1piNGHg7O7lxgRyItR1U5BzB52q7GmCHe_HPJBsUHv8RcZCgqLPPtyngPmDjvy7pZDprPNK6ihKVEgQ7HqmbDSPXZ1aHPkBDs9re49u_Q_jI04etmtK7E0GIdxhKWCd-p4TR7b_b0JdnwzJOF6z4XaJQOgNU8kazJr5Mo96zxQpUlsKWPSumEmSfynkGeMDgkM-O1mN59LKp0p4kt-2O2IIFrlc8289ZbCSO6JghtvDsLsFDA3VxLV3Irn2W3KQ8sHg_TdwB-0g0WX9J-WTwedVYzj2a7uNtH377ZIritTXKqRw1qeQ6mkpxQ0h_OVMIl8XUiEC0Zj1KP50tUK8](https://www.lmcu.org/?__cf_chl_jschl_tk__=fe835fdc1e7e2f5b2857ab5eb4be84e67d0e8c42-1592506549-0-AQ3E1piNGHg7O7lxgRyItR1U5BzB52q7GmCHe_HPJBsUHv8RcZCgqLPPtyngPmDjvy7pZDprPNK6ihKVEgQ7HqmbDSPXZ1aHPkBDs9re49u_Q_jI04etmtK7E0GIdxhKWCd-p4TR7b_b0JdnwzJOF6z4XaJQOgNU8kazJr5Mo96zxQpUlsKWPSumEmSfynkGeMDgkM-O1mN59LKp0p4kt-2O2IIFrlc8289ZbCSO6JghtvDsLsFDA3VxLV3Irn2W3KQ8sHg_TdwB-0g0WX9J-WTwedVYzj2a7uNtH377ZIritTXKqRw1qeQ6mkpxQ0h_OVMIl8XUiEC0Zj1KP50tUK8)

I checked with Postman, and sure enough - I got the 503 error there as well. As far as I could tell, the server (or reverse proxy in front of it) was inspecting the headers of the request, and invalidating the request based on them. I fooled around a little, moving headers from the browser request into Postman, and finally figured out that it is a combination of the `cookie` and `User-Agent` headers being set that allows the request to be served.

The `User-Agent` header is not allowed to have the specified chrome version, I have it working with version 83 here.
The `cookkie` header is something that the browser will populate from my first visit to the site in the browser. So that is a bit harder to handle in your code. I tried to fetch it in code with `connection.getHeaderField("set-cookie")` but that cookie does not seem to cut it.

But! I was able to make the code work, when taking the `cookie` from my browser, and setting it manually in code, along with the `User-Agent`:

```java
    public HttpURLConnection pingHttpUrl(String url) throws IOException {

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        try {
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

            // This one does not work for the reason of the chrome version apparently
            // conn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76 Safari/537.36");
            conn.addRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.97 Safari/537.36");
            conn.addRequestProperty("cookie", "<cookie value from the browser, from the header on a successful request>");

            conn.setConnectTimeout(2000);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
            conn.setReadTimeout(10000);
            conn.connect();
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(String.format("Caught exception : %s", e.getMessage()));
            throw new IOException();
        }

        return conn;
    }
```

I later found out that is is the cookie value from the `cf_clearance` key in the cookie that makes the difference.

Comment: Is there any generalization for this solution because I need to get response code for a big set of sites and this changes might affect other sites' response codes. Or will this also work with other sites which are already giving 200 status codes?

I basically want to know is there any generalization or any other way to get it resolved without affecting other sites' status codes.